# variable inside pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, dynamic

```
var seperator = ',', group = 'red, blue';
//group.search(seperator/g) - g is not defined
group.search(/seperator/g) // looks for "seperator"
group.search('/' + seperator + '/g') // doesn't seem to find my "seperator"
```

And with that I'm out of ideas... How do I get my `seperator` within expression?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+regular+expression+from+variable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+regular+expression+from+variable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create new regexp Object

```
var test = new RegExp(seperator, 'g');
group.search(test)
```

Comment: +1 See also section *How to Use The JavaScript RegExp Object* in *[JavaScript RegExp Object - Using Regular Expressions with Client Side Scripting](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)*.

Comment: Ah, I wanted to slip through it the shorthand way. Okay, thanks! :) Oh, just noticed `RexExp` (highlighted too)... typo or what?

Comment: Yeah, typo :) @ipr101 fixed my code already. Should be `RegExp`